# How to use SortedList in RecyclerView with Android data binding library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Android data binding provides several Observable data interfaces including ObservableList. But SortedList (introduced in recent version of RecyclerView library) does not extend List at all.

How could I use SortedList for RecyclerView with Android data binding library?

Comment: This not working for you? https://github.com/radzio/android-data-binding-recyclerview

Comment: @Jürgen'Kashban'Wahlmann I already checked that project, but unfortunately not. So I also filed an issue for the auther: https://github.com/radzio/android-data-binding-recyclerview/issues/7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inspired by George Mount, I have implemented my version of ObservableSortedList with full functionalities from the original SortedList, including:

- Batch update. Just call beginBatchedUpdates() and endBatchedUpdates() as of SortedList.
- De-dup and smart refresh. The callback in the constructor is responsible for ordering, de-dup and content differentiation.

Full code:

```
public class ObservableSortedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements ObservableList<T> {

  /** @see android.support.v7.util.SortedList.Callback */
  public interface Callback<T2> {
    /** @see android.support.v7.util.SortedList.Callback#compare(Object, Object) */
    int compare(T2 o1, T2 o2);
    /** @see android.support.v7.util.SortedList.Callback#areItemsTheSame(Object, Object) */
    boolean areItemsTheSame(T2 item1, T2 item2);
    /** @see android.support.v7.util.SortedList.Callback#areContentsTheSame(Object, Object) */
    boolean areContentsTheSame(T2 oldItem, T2 newItem);
  }

  public ObservableSortedList(final Class<T> klass, final Callback<T> callback) {
    mList = new SortedList<>(klass, new CallbackWrapper<>(callback));
  }

  /** @see SortedList#beginBatchedUpdates() */
  public void beginBatchedUpdates() { mList.beginBatchedUpdates(); }
  /** @see SortedList#endBatchedUpdates() */
  public void endBatchedUpdates() { mList.endBatchedUpdates(); }

  @Override public boolean add(final T item) {
    sTlsUpdated.set(false);
    mList.add(item);
    return sTlsUpdated.get();   // May be set by Callback.onInserted() or onChanged().
  }

  @Override public T set(final int location, final T object) {
    final T old = mList.get(location);
    mList.updateItemAt(location, cast(object));
    return old;
  }

  @Override public int indexOf(final Object object) {
    try {
      return mList.indexOf(cast(object));
    } catch (final ClassCastException ignored) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  @Override public boolean remove(final Object object) {
    try {
      return mList.remove(cast(object));
    } catch (final ClassCastException ignored) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") private T cast(final Object object) { return (T) object; }

  @Override public boolean contains(final Object object) { return indexOf(object) != SortedList.INVALID_POSITION; }
  @Override public T get(final int location) { return mList.get(location); }
  @Override public int size() { return mList.size(); }
  @Override public void clear() { mList.clear(); }
  @Override public T remove(final int location) { return mList.removeItemAt(location); }

  /* ObservableList */

  @Override public void addOnListChangedCallback(final OnListChangedCallback<? extends ObservableList<T>> callback) {
    if (mListeners == null) this.mListeners = new ListChangeRegistry();
    mListeners.add(callback);
  }

  @Override public void removeOnListChangedCallback(final OnListChangedCallback<? extends ObservableList<T>> callback) {
    if (mListeners == null) return;
    mListeners.remove(callback);
  }

  private final SortedList<T> mList;
  private static final ThreadLocal<Boolean> sTlsUpdated = new ThreadLocal<>();
  private transient @Nullable ListChangeRegistry mListeners = new ListChangeRegistry();

  public class CallbackWrapper<T2> extends SortedList.Callback<T2> {

    @Override public final void onInserted(final int position, final int count) {
      sTlsUpdated.set(true);
      if (mListeners != null) mListeners.notifyInserted(ObservableSortedList.this, position, count);
    }

    @Override public final void onRemoved(final int position, final int count) {
      if (mListeners != null) mListeners.notifyRemoved(ObservableSortedList.this, position, count);
    }

    @Override public final void onMoved(final int fromPosition, final int toPosition) {
      if (mListeners != null) mListeners.notifyMoved(ObservableSortedList.this, fromPosition, toPosition, 1);
    }

    @Override public final void onChanged(final int position, final int count) {
      sTlsUpdated.set(true);
      if (mListeners != null) mListeners.notifyChanged(ObservableSortedList.this, position, count);
    }

    @Override public int compare(final T2 o1, final T2 o2) { return mCallback.compare(o1, o2); }
    @Override public boolean areContentsTheSame(final T2 oldItem, final T2 newItem) { return mCallback.areContentsTheSame(oldItem, newItem); }
    @Override public boolean areItemsTheSame(final T2 item1, final T2 item2) { return mCallback.areItemsTheSame(item1, item2); }
    public CallbackWrapper(final Callback<T2> callback) { mCallback = callback; }

    private final Callback<T2> mCallback;
  }
}
```

Comment: what should I do in @BindingAdapter?

Answer (score 9):

To make a SortedList support Observability in data binding, you must implement the interface yourself. Since there is conflict in the API, it appears that you'll have to wrap it. Something like this:

```
public class ObservableSortedList<T> implements ObservableList<T> {
    private final SortedList<T> mList;
    private final ListChangeRegistry mListeners = new ListChangeRegistry();

    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        int index = mList.add(item);
        mListeners.notifyInserted(this, index, 1);
    }

    @Observable
    public void addOnListChangedCallback(OnListChangedCallback<? extends ObservableList<T>> callback) {
        mListeners.add(callback);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: In this way, I have to give up many advantages of using the SortedList directly, like batch update, de-dup, smart refresh (avoid refresh content-unchanged update). I think it's not the optimal way.

Comment: You can still have those, but access them through methods that don't have conflicting signatures. For example, add(T) returns an int in SortedList and boolean in List. It will just take a little effort, but you'll still be able to get all the advantages of the SortedList.

Comment: @GeorgeMount are there plans to fix this? kind of silly that we cannot use `SortedList` out of the box with databinding, not to mention parceling a `SortedList`